# How to use theos extra framework?

Tags: theos

Theos lists it supports

> Third party frameworks can be placed inside $THEOS/lib, and utilised with instance_EXTRA_FRAMEWORKS. (kirb)

But I am not sure how to make it work or trouble shooting, can someone explain what's this for, and how to use it? If I already build a binary, and the binary needs some frameworks, how to do it?

I tried to follow the samples like putting frameworks under $THEOS/lib and add the flag, but when it runs, for example I am adding AWSCore.framework and AWSS3.framework, it reports `library not loaded, image not found`

I need to understand how the framework is added into my binary, and what's the run path etc. and how to debug where goes off. Thank you. Does the binary already contains the framework, or I should copy it to somewhere?